# .htaccess file not redirecting assets to other domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make my PHP site pull images in /assets/u/ from another server using a redirect in the .htaccess file. The .htaccess is definitely being used. I know because I set 'AllowOverride All' in the sites root directory in HTTPD config and even tested it by putting in incorrect syntax on purpose and confirming that I get an internal server error. But my images in /assets/u/ still aren't being pulled from the other server. Below is my .htaccess file...

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^((www)|(draft))\.
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\/*$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Start of attempted redirect #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*(/assets/u/).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ http://assets.otherserver.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# End of attempted redirect #

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Please explain your question clearly you want to fetch images from another server or redirect particular url to another server?

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar I want to fetch images from another server

Comment: Fetch means you want to display images from another server or you want to download the images or to redirect to the images?

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar ... display images from another server.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your question but here is my 1st attempt.

I am assuming you are using `assets/u/` as link in `<img href="assets/u/test.jpg">` tag, and your actual files are stored in `http://assets.otherserver.com` address,

For this task I suggest you to use `mod_proxy` to display your images without redirecting the urls try with below rule I am assuming you are able to arrange your .htaccess without breaking the other rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/assets/u/(.+?)$
RewriteRule ^ http://assets.otherserver.com/%1 [P,L]
```

For above rule to work you must have enabled below.

```
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
```

Uncomment above lines in httpd.conf.

Inform me of any update.

Answer (score 0):

As you use `RewriteBase` Directive, try to remove the the first `/`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(assets/u/).*$ [NC]
```